# bitbake do_configure: how to set the path from where to run do_configure

Tags: bitbake, openembedded

The bb file has the source directory variable set to a specific path

```
S = ${THISDIR}/MySources
```

There is no SRC_URI in the bb file as the source is already extracted in the path where the bb file is present.

The issue is when the do_configure is run it is run from the `$WORKDIR` location. However there is a need to run the do_configure from the source dir that is from `$S`. How to set this, even the log for do_configure run log shows a change directory to `WORKDIR` and then a do configure something like this

```
...
...
cd [path to workdir]

do_configure
```

How to make the do_configure run from the source directory `${S}`.
The source is added as a layer in the bitbake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way would be to either package the source code, or ensure that all files are copied to workdir. (Preferably, a subdirectory).

However, if you insist on building your application in the recipe directory, it's quite likely that this will work of you add the line 

`B = "${S}"`

after the line where you define `S`.